# boost::filesystem not working in Google Cloud Run (using gVisor)

Tags: c++, boost, google-cloud-run, boost-filesystem, gvisor

I've created a docker container (`ubuntu:focal`) with a C++ application that is using `boost::filesystem` (v1.76.0) to create some directories while processing data. It works if I run the container locally, but it fails when deployed to Cloud Run.

A simple statement like

```
boost::filesystem::exists(boost::filesystem::current_path())
```

fails with *"Invalid argument '/current/path/here'"*. **It doesn't work in this C++ application, but from a Python app running equivalent statements, it does work.**

Reading [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#sandbox) I can see Cloud Run is using gVisor and not all the system calls are fully supported (link: https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/linux/amd64/), nevertheless I would expect simple calls to work: check if a directory exists, create a directory, remove,...

Maybe I'm doing something wrong when deploying my container. Is there any way to work around it? Any `boost` configuration I can use to prevent it from using some syscalls?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tried with `std::filesystem` (C++17), it works. Probably I'll change the codebase, but still if someone can contribute a work around it could be useful for future reference.

Comment: I think you need to report to the boost devs. With a reproducing case. In this case likely platform and permissions are essential to understanding the cause. I think this has been the second time in abiut a month that I see a similar issue. I don't think we're need a workaround, i think we need a library QoI fix (or gVisor does, if they notice the problem for their customers)

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue when running SlideIO (which use boost::filesystem) in google cloud function. It works fine locally but always returns "boost::filesystem::status: Invalid argument [system:22]" on google cloud.

I switched to [second generation execution env](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments) for Cloud Run which provides full Linux compatibility rather than system call emulation. And the code works fine again.